# How to know if an object is visible or hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, properties, display

First of all: I am sorry for my bad english.
I want to know if an object has a different display property than "none".
I have used:

```html
$(element).is(":hidden")
$(element).is(":visible")
```

but for some reason the result is always false and the display property is undefined. 
[Here is a fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/aL9581qy/1/)

So, what can I do to know if an object is hidden or visible?

Comment: You have to prefix the id with `#`.....`$("#visible").is(":visible");`

Comment: yes thanks, so embarassing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marmun said you need to use the Id selector which is `#` so:

```
$("#element").is(":hidden");
$("#element").is(":visible");
```

will work.